# Group start and stop dates based on boolean column

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by

I have the following logger table on a SQL server. This table logs when a motor starts and stops.

| Date | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01 08:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 2022-03-01 08:30:00.000 | 0 |
| 2022-03-01 09:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 2022-03-01 09:30:00.000 | 1 |
| 2022-03-01 10:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 2022-03-01 10:30:00.000 | 1 |
| 2022-03-01 11:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 2022-03-01 12:30:00.000 | 0 |

```
Where Status=1 is working and 0 is stopped
```

I would like to identify both the start and stop time on every period and calculate the elapsed time (working time in minutes). The next table is the wanted result.

| Start | Stop | Working_Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01 08:00:00.000 | 2022-03-01 08:30:00.000 | 30 |
| 2022-03-01 09:30:00.000 | 2022-03-01 11:00:00.000 | 90 |

Moreover if you put some thoughts and comments on the procedure, (as a beginner on SQL) this will help me a lot!

**UPDATE**

As i have mentioned i'm developing my learning on SQL... the following sources gave me a perspective on how to proceed but i was confused after a point, on how to adapt to my case. More specific on how to check datetime difference with previous record testing lag() and DATEDIFF().

https://community.looker.com/sql-10/sql-pattern-summarizing-entities-with-a-start-end-date-over-time-4868

[Count entries grouped by start and end time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076543/count-entries-grouped-by-start-and-end-time)

[Sum values of column in time window defined start/stop event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65505064/sum-values-of-column-in-time-window-defined-start-stop-event)

Comment: `I've reviewed some well-made solutions` What is the issue with those solutions ?

Comment: were solutions aimed for more SQL familiar users

Answer (score -1):

Find the working block using analytic SQL, and then group by working block

```
SELECT block, min(date) date_start, max(date_end) date_end  
FROM 
(SELECT date, 
        date_end, 
        status, 
        prev_status, 
        status*sum(case when prev_status=0 then status else 0 end) OVER (ORDER BY date) block  
 FROM   
    (SELECT date, 
            lead(date) OVER (ORDER BY date) date_end, 
            status, 
            COALESCE(lag(status) OVER (ORDER BY date),0) prev_status 
      FROM logger) as x ) as y 
WHERE block > 0
GROUP BY block
```